# Use result of query with single result in SELECT

Tags: sqlite

I'm using Sqlite and I found out that `INSERT` does not return the just inserted record with the automatically created primary key.

To solve this issue I found out I can use `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`. This returns the value that I need.

I need this value to update a field in the record of my database.

Is there any way I could form a `SELECT` query that has the result of that query built in?

```
UPDATE events SET url='query executed' WHERE eventId = <value of above query should come here>
```

Comment: Care must be taken: you should perform both commands inside a single transaction, or you can get your database corrupted!

Comment: What language are you using to access the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` returns the value that you need then put it there as a subquery. Subquery must be in `(your_subquery)` brackets.

Comment: This was the answer indeed. It looks quite obvious though. Thanks a lot! :)